# Symbol already defined differently VB

Tags: vb6, libreoffice-basic

I'm trying to compile the following code, and I keep getting an error. I got this erro before multiple times so I was forced to use workaround functions. This time I'm really tired of this issue and I need to know what's wrong here.

```
sub SQL_AddTestResults (byval sData as string, byval testID as integer)

   dim i as integer
   dim dataChain as string
   dim aData (Split(sData, ";").length) as string

   aData = Split(sData, ";")

   for i = 0 to aData.Length

      if(i = 4) then
          goto skip
      elseif (i = 68) then
          goto skip
      elseif (i = 72) then
          goto skip
      end if

      if(i = aData.length) then
          dataChain = dataChain & aData(i)
      else
          dataChain = dataChain & aData(i) & ", "
      end if

      skip:
   next

   MsgBox (dataChain)

   SQL_statement = "INSERT INTO ""TestData"" VALUES (" & dataChain & ");"   
   Stmt = connection.createStatement()
   Stmt.executeUpdate(SQL_statement)
end sub
```

Compiling this code gives me the following error on "for i = 0 to aData.Length" line:

*Basic syntax error.*

*Symbol aData already defined differently.*

Have no idea why. Apologies if that's a trivial problem, but I'm completely new to VB. C++ didn't prepare me for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrays in classic VB don't have a "length" property. I'm not sure where you got that from.

The way to get the bounds of an array in classic VB is with the LBound and UBound functions.

```
for i = LBound(aData) to UBound(aData)
```

This way you can even handle arrays that don't have 0 as the starting index, as yes, one of VB's wonderful quirks is that it lets you use any range of numbers for your indexes.

VB6 isn't a language I'd recommend for new development. If you're trying to learn something new, there are plenty of other options. As you've no doubt noticed, it's harder and harder to find documentation on how classic VB does things, and how it differs from VBScript and VB.NET. If you need to be maintaining an older VB6 code base, I'd recommend finding a used book somewhere that goes over VB6 syntax and usage.

Comment: The tag on the question suggests he's using the VB-inspired macro language in LibreOffice, so he probably doesn't have much choice in the matter. :-)

Comment: @CodyGray Well, I'm not as familiar with that language, so I assumed the vb6 tag meant he was using VB6 and just was somehow connecting to LibreOffice with it. Hopefully the answer is useful anyway. Amazing how there just keeps on being more and more languages called "Basic".

Answer (score 1):

Try this code corrected code:

```
sub SQL_AddTestResults (byval sData as string, byval testID as integer)
dim i as integer
dim dataChain as string
dim aData as variant

aData = Split(sData, ";")

for i = 0 to ubound(aData)

  if(i = 4) then
      goto skip
  elseif (i = 68) then
      goto skip
  elseif (i = 72) then
      goto skip
  end if

  if(i = ubound(aData)) then
      dataChain = dataChain & aData(i)
  else
      dataChain = dataChain & aData(i) & ", "
  end if

  skip:
  next
  MsgBox (dataChain)

  SQL_statement = "INSERT INTO ""TestData"" VALUES (" & dataChain & ");"   
  Stmt = connection.createStatement()
  Stmt.executeUpdate(SQL_statement)
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

What I could gather, you are defining aData twice but in different ways -

```
dim aData (Split(sData, ";").length) as string

aData = Split(sData, ";")
```

aData length will return an integer of the actual length whilst you are asking it to return a string, and you are using it in your integer loop for i as counter.

Immediately after that you are telling it to return just some data causing the crash. Rather use another nominator to hold the two different kinds of returned information you need -

```
dim aData (Split(sData, ";").length) as Long ''Rather use long as the length might exceed the integer type. Use the same for i, change integer to long

Dim bData = Split(sData, ";") as String

for i = 0 to aData.Length

  if(i = 4) then
      goto skip
  elseif (i = 68) then
      goto skip
  elseif (i = 72) then
      goto skip
  end if

  if(i = aData.length) then
      dataChain = dataChain & bData(i)
  else
      dataChain = dataChain & bData(i) & ", "
  end if

  skip:
next
```